# ¿Cómo obtener la colección de datos dentro de un LOOP en PL SQL Oracle?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Cuento con un Stored procedure como el siguiente:

```
create or replace procedure SP_TESTING(param1 IN Tipo1, param2 OUT Tipo2)
AS
index INT;
size INT;
BEING
size := param1.count;
FOR index IN 1..size LOOP
SELECT nombre, apellido BULK COLLECT INTO param2 FROM Persona WHERE id = param1(index);
END LOOP;
END SP_TESTING;
```

Donde Tipo1:

```
create or replace Type "TIPO1" IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
```

Donde Tipo2:

```
create or replace Type "Tipo2" IS TABLE OF PERSONA_T;
```

Y donde PERSONA_T:

```
create or replace Type "PERSONA_T" FORCE AS OBJECT(nombre VARCHAR2(30), apellido VARCHAR(30));
```

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de invocar el SP no encuentro la manera de extraer todos los registros volcados en "param2", la idea del SP es que pueda encontrar y proporcionar registros a partir de una serie de "id" proporcionados, es decir:

```
declare
param1IN Tipo1;
param2IN Tipo2;
BEGIN
param1IN := Tipo1();
param1IN.EXTEND(2);
param1IN(1):= 4;
param1IN(2):= 18;
SP_TESTING(param1IN, param2IN);
END;
```

En esta invocación solo logro obtener en "param2IN" un único registro cuando realmente yo intento obtener dos registros cuando el id sea igual a 4 y 18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si a alguien le es de utilidad, dejo aquí la solución.

La solución fue cambiar la consulta dentro del SP haciendo uso de la sentencia "MEMBER OF"
por lo que la consulta quedaría como:

```
SELECT nombre, apellido BULK COLLECT INTO param2 FROM Persona WHERE id MEMBER OF param1
```

Esta sentencia hace inútil el uso del LOOP por lo que ya no es necesario.